# Swift: How to programmatically load a picture into a window?

Tags: swift, image, macos, cocoa

I tried it with following code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!! //I don't understand this line

    let imageView = NSImageView()
    imageView.image = NSImage(byReferencingURL: IMAGE)
    window.contentView?.addSubview(imageView)
```

I have no compile and run time errors and the NSImage seems to have loaded the picture correctly. - But unfortunatelly it does not show up in my window.

**EDIT**:
The frame property hat to be set. Following code centers the picture in the window:

```
let imageView = NSImageView()
let image = NSImage(byReferencingURL: IMAGE_URL)
imageView.image = image
imageView.frame = self.window.contentView!.bounds
imageView.autoresizingMask = [.ViewWidthSizable, .ViewHeightSizable]                                
self.window.contentView?.addSubview(imageView)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmatically add an image view to your window you will want to use an `NSImageView` object and set the image property. Below I've created a simple function that you can place in you window's View Controller. In addition, you should set other `NSImageView` properties (e.g. `frame`) to achieve the desired result.

```
func loadImageView() {
    /* Create an image view */
    let imageView = NSImageView()
    /* Set image property and replace name with your image file's name */
    imageView.image = NSImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_FILE_NAME_HERE")

    /* Add the new imageView to the main view */
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the last line to: `window.view.addSubview(imageView)` Now I am getting the error: "Value of type '(NSView, stringForToolTip: NSToolTipTag, point: NSPoint, userData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> String' has no member 'addSubview'" `window` is: `@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!`

Comment: @PjotrC What class are you implementing the function in? If it is in your main ViewController subclass you should not be accessing the view through the `window` property.

Comment: I am working in the class _AppDelegate_ which gets generated by Xcode automatically. It seems, that I have to use _contentView_ instead of just _view_ (please see updated question). I don't which properties I should set to which values...